# I want to use a component lifecycle method the is initialized before render

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

I wanted to use a React component lifecycle method before render() to update my mobx state. They say UNSAFE_componentWillMount will be deprecated and should not be use. So what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to control at the first or any new update state.

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)
```

Or use [componenDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to replace it, although this is not before render.